Minimal config.txt for enabling UART0
I am attempting to connect to the UART0 on my Raspberry Pi 4B.  I have shorted together GPIO pins 14 and 15 (pins 8 an 10 on the header).  I then run picocom /dev/ttyAMA0 and see if it's echoing (it is not).
I have tried a wide variety of config.txt options to get it working (there are many), to the point that I think there might be something wrong with my hardware.  Does anyone have a complete config.txt example that will enable the UART0 so that I can connect to it using picocom?

Do not fiddle with config.txt; enable serial in raspi-config.
tty/AMA0 is connected to Bluetooth.
DO NOT use AMA0 use /tty/serial0.

Thank you.  I just did a gpio test and it turns out pin 14 failed, so it was a hardware issue.
